# VHDL - Hierarchical block <FF> is unconnected in block <Demux>. It will be removed from the design

Tags: vhdl

[image: The wanted circuit]
NOTE: D and filtered_right should be connected in the picture.

Hello guys, I am having a difficulty with creating a circuit as one on the picture. The idea is that there is a rotary knot and with every rotation to the right some counter would increment and every rotation to the left it will decrement. When reached some value, I want some LEDs to glow. The principle on which it works is as following: if the left signal activates first, than it is rotation to right, otherwise a rotation to left. But when filtered, the logic is as it is in the code. If there is a rising edge (if the Q and D differ on the D Flip Flop), and the D is a '1', but meanwhile the other signal is '1' then it is a rotation to right, otherwise, a rotaton to left.

I am using a Spartan 3AN-Starter Kit FPGA. I described the filter and DFF in two separate entities and used them as components in my main project, but the warnings continually signal that they remain unconnected no matter what I do, even though it successfully synthesize. I would like to know why is that.

Here is a drawing of the circuit, my VHDL code and the warnings:

This is the main project:

```
--Main project
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use WORK.all;

entity Demux is


    port ( led : OUT std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            turn_right, turn_left,clk: IN std_logic);

        subtype smallint is integer range 0 to 80;

end Demux;

architecture Behavioral of Demux is

component dff
port (set,reset,D,clk: IN std_logic;    
        Q: OUT std_logic);
end component;

component filter
port (clk,turn_right,turn_left: in std_logic;
        filtered_right, filtered_left: out std_logic);
end component;

signal counter: smallint:=0;
signal Q: std_logic;
signal filtered_right: std_logic :='0'; 
signal filtered_left: std_logic := '0';
signal set: std_logic;
signal reset: std_logic;
begin

    set <= '0';
    reset <='0';

    FF: dff port map (
            set=>set,
            reset=>reset,
            D=>filtered_right,
            clk=>clk,
            Q=>Q);

    filt: filter port map (
            turn_right=>turn_right,
            turn_left=>turn_left,
            filtered_right=>filtered_right,
            filtered_left=>filtered_left,
            clk=>clk);

    compare: process (clk,Q) is
    begin
        if ((clk'event) and (clk='1')) then
            if ((filtered_right /= Q) and (filtered_right='1')) then
                    if (filtered_left = '1') then
                        counter <= counter + 1;
                    elsif (filtered_left = '0') then
                        counter <= counter - 1;
                    end if;
            end if;

            if (counter>80) or (counter<0) then
                counter <=0;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process compare;

        led(0) <= '1' when counter = 10;
        led(1) <= '1' when counter = 20;
        led(2) <= '1' when counter = 30;
        led(3) <= '1' when counter = 40;
        led(4) <= '1' when counter = 50;
        led(5) <= '1' when counter = 60;
        led(6) <= '1' when counter = 70;
        led(7) <= '1' when counter = 80;

end Behavioral;
```

Here is my realization of the DFF:

```
Library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

Entity dff is
    port (D,set,reset,clk: in std_logic;
            Q:      out std_logic);
end dff;

Architecture behavioral of dff is
begin

    dff: process (clk,set,reset,D) is
    begin
        if ((clk'event) and (clk='1')) then
            if (reset='1') then
                Q<='0';
            elsif (set='1') then
                Q<='1';
            else
                Q<=D;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process dff;
end behavioral;
```

Here is my realization of the filter:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity filter is
    port (clk,turn_right,turn_left: in std_logic;
            filtered_right, filtered_left: out std_logic);
end filter;

architecture Behavioral of filter is
begin
filter: process(clk, turn_right,turn_left) is
        variable rotary_conc: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        variable filtered_left_temp, filtered_right_temp: std_logic;
    begin
        if ((clk'event) and (clk='1')) then
            rotary_conc:=turn_left & turn_right;
            case rotary_conc is
                when "00" => filtered_right_temp := '0';
                                 filtered_left_temp  := filtered_left_temp;

                when "01" => filtered_right_temp := filtered_right_temp;
                                 filtered_left_temp  := '0';

                when "10" => filtered_right_temp := filtered_right_temp;
                                 filtered_left_temp  :='1';

                when "11" => filtered_right_temp := '1';
                                 filtered_left_temp  := filtered_left_temp;

                when OTHERS => filtered_right_temp := filtered_right_temp;
                                    filtered_left_temp  := filtered_left_temp;
            end case;
            filtered_right<=filtered_right_temp;
            filtered_left<=filtered_left_temp;
        end if;
    end process filter;
end Behavioral;
```

Just so you know, the filter exists because there is a chatter because of the mechanic nature of the rotary knot. That chatter can produce false incrementation/decrementation. To avoid it - I filter it.

Warnings:

```
WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block <FF> is unconnected in block <Demux>.
   It will be removed from the design.
WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block <filt> is unconnected in block <Demux>.
   It will be removed from the design.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <FF/Q> of sequential type is unconnected in block <Demux>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <filt/filtered_right_temp> of sequential type is unconnected in block <Demux>.
WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <filt/filtered_left_temp> of sequential type is unconnected in block <Demux>.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding some `else` clauses to your `when` clauses in your Demux.vhd.

```
led(0) <= '1' when counter = 10 else '0';
led(1) <= '1' when counter = 20 else '0';
led(2) <= '1' when counter = 30 else '0';
led(3) <= '1' when counter = 40 else '0';
led(4) <= '1' when counter = 50 else '0';
led(5) <= '1' when counter = 60 else '0';
led(6) <= '1' when counter = 70 else '0';
led(7) <= '1' when counter = 80 else '0';
```

Without these `else` clauses, the synthesizer may consider `led` to always be "11111111" and thus not depending on the inputs.